# How can make Django permission_required decorator not to redirect already logged-in users to login page, but display some message

Tags: django, decorator, django-authentication

How can make Django permission_required decorator not to redirect already logged-in users to login page, but display some message like Insufficient permissions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution would be to write your own decorator to do this. Something like this:

```
decorator_with_arguments = lambda decorator: lambda *args, **kwargs: lambda func: decorator(func, *args, **kwargs)

@decorator_with_arguments
def custom_permission_required(function, perm):
    def _function(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.has_perm(perm):
            return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            request.user.message_set.create(message = "What are you doing here?!")
            # Return a response or redirect to referrer or some page of your choice
    return _function
```

You can then decorate your view thus:

```
@custom_permission_required('my_perm')
def my_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    #Do stuff
```

Comment: Is that request.user.message_set.create() really a built-in function in Django or just a pseudo example?

Comment: @PaulLo: Django's built-in `User` model had (has?) a function named `message_set.create()` which created a message instance. Not sure if it is still there.

Comment: I just took a look at Django's official site, uesr.message_set was deprecated since 1.2, and they recommended using the message framework instead: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/messages/

Answer (score 12):

Since django 1.4 `permission_required` has a `raise_exception` parameter that you can set to True to have an unauthorized [PermissionDenied](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/exceptions/#permissiondenied) exception raised

Eg. to give an exemple on a Class Based View:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required
...

class MyView(TemplateView):

    @method_decorator(permission_required('can_do_something', raise_exception=True))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(MyView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Ref:[permission_required decorator doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.permission_required)

Comment: I think the question still wants users to be redirected when the user is not logged. This will not redirect users that are not logged in.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own decorator to replace django's `permission_required` decorator:

```
from django.utils import six
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def permission_required(perm, login_url=None, raise_exception=True):
    def check_perms(user):
        if isinstance(perm, six.string_types):
            perms = (perm, )
        else:
            perms = perm
        if user.has_perms(perms):
            return True
        if raise_exception and user.pk:
            raise PermissionDenied
        return False
    return user_passes_test(check_perms, login_url=login_url)
```

And use it the same way:

```
@permission_required('app.permission')
def view_page(request):
    # your view function
```

Logged in users with no permission will get a 403 forbidden error. Those who are not logged in will be redirected to the login page.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this question requires two pieces

- Users that are already logged in do not get redirected to the login page
- Users that are not logged in **do not get redirected**

@Manoj Govindan's answer nor @Stefano's answer will not work. @Lidor's answer will work, but he has fully re-implemented the `permission_required` function.

Here is a simpler way:

```
@login_required
@permission_required('hi there', raise_exception=True)
def blah(request):
    pass
```

With this, if the user is not logged in, they will be redirected. If they are but they don't have permissions, they will be down an error.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but learned about `raise_exception` parameter at the  `@permission_required` decorator!
this parameter is `False` by default, but once you pass it the `True` value, it will automatically redirect the without permission user to the `403.html` page! (if there was any `403.html` page in the root of your project, otherwise shows the server 403 forbidden page!
[read more in Django docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/views/#the-403-http-forbidden-view)

```py
@permission_required('app_name.view_model', raise_exception=True)
    def some_model_view(request):
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a parameter "login_url" to the decorator:

```
@permission_required("my_app.add_user", login_url="url_name")
```