# Django permission_required error message?

Tags: django

I've added this decorator to one of my views

```
@permission_required('codename')
```

When a user visits that page and doesn't have the required permissions, he is redirected the login page, but it doesn't really tell him *why* he's been redirected there. Worse yet, if he logs in, and *still* doesn't have the permissions, he's going to be completely clueless as to why he can't access that page!

Isn't there a way I can tap into the messages framework and post an error at the same time?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251151/how-can-make-django-permission-required-decorator-not-to-redirect-already-logged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ***can*** tap into the messages framework and provide an error message. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251151/how-can-make-django-permission-required-decorator-not-to-redirect-already-logged/1252205#1252205) to an identical question.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure what version of Django you are using, but in Django 1.4 and higher you can use:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required

@permission_required('app.permission',raise_exception=True)
def myView(request):
    #your view code
```

This will raise a 403 exception and if you have a 403.html page at the base of your template folder it will server this out.

If you are using class based views:

```
from django.views.generic.base import View
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

class MyView(View):

    @method_decorator(permission_required('app.permission',raise_exception=True)
    def get(self, request):
        #your GET view
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could use login_url parameter in this decorator to redirect to some other page, rather than login page. Or you can simply write your own decorator based on the code from django:

```
def permission_required(perm, login_url=None):
    """
    Decorator for views that checks whether a user has a particular permission
    enabled, redirecting to the log-in page if necessary.
    """
    return user_passes_test(lambda u: u.has_perm(perm), login_url=login_url)
```

Simply change `login_url` to some `redirect_to` and it won't cause any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Use `@permission_required_or_403('codename')`

This will redirect the users to a 403 'permission denied' error page.

Comment: This is not included in standard Django, but in django-guardian.