# Modifying django decorator function, Permissionn_required

Tags: python, django, decorator

By default the decorator `@permission_required($SOME_PERMISSION)`, checks if the requesting user has the required permission to request this view or not , if it doesn't, it's redirected to the login page or any other specified page.(e.g. if the user is not logged in he's redirected to the login page).
Here's my problem , i want to redirect a not logged in user to the login page, but there might be a logged in user that doesn't have the required permission, by default that user is being redirected to the login page and well he's already logged in so , he's redirected again to the page he had requested and here happens a loop.
So what i want to do is to change the behavior of this decorator (write an equivalent code in my view function instead of using @permission_required) to check whether the user can't see the requested page cause he's not logged in , or he is logged in but doesn't have the permission, and then redirect him accordingly to the correct page. 
any help would be greatly appreciated :)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please ask a specific question. Asking for "any help" isn't.

Comment: try using request.user.is_authenticated() https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/

Answer (score 3):

Just pass the `login_url` parameter to `permission_required`, like:

```
@permission_required($SOME_PERMISSION, login_url='/my/custom/page')
```

Comment: If you do this, then you should add the `@login_required` decorator above the `@permission_required` otherwise not-logged-in-users would get redirected to your custom page too.

Comment: @themanatuf Thanks ! using them both together does the trick , but one thing , the url now looks like : '....next=/jobs/tree/', meaning the next page's url is there !( cause of redirection ), can't we do sth for the url, not to have that next=... part ? 
thanks again

Comment: @SpiXel - I haven't done this personally, but I did find this for you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950409/suppress-next-blah-behavior-in-djangos-login-required-decorator

I think the middleware solution will ax the "next" for every redirect. I'm not sure that's what you're looking for. Otherwise the custom decorator might be the best choice. Again, I haven't actually tried this, but it should work.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is this answer:

[How can make Django permission_required decorator not to redirect already logged-in users to login page, but display some message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251151/how-can-make-django-permission-required-decorator-not-to-redirect-already-logged)

I hope that helps!

Comment: Any specifics on the down-vote? The linked answer shows how to create a custom decorator which is exactly what the original poster is asking for.

Comment: someone seems to be a bit trigger-happy on the down arrow today in #django - no way of knowing who - just ignore it :-)