# lambda inside lambda inside lambda

Tags: lambda, python-decorators, django-1.11

I'd like to use a decorator for a login page and I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251151/how-can-make-django-permission-required-decorator-not-to-redirect-already-logged). It contains a funky bit of code that I don't quite follow:

```
decorator_with_arguments = lambda decorator: lambda *args, **kwargs: lambda func: decorator(func, *args, **kwargs)
```

Could someone break this down for me as I can't quite grasp what's meant to be going on here?